# Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.URLRequest' to 'Alamofire.URLConvertible'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to do a post request using Alamofire with a body:

```
let credential = URLCredential(user: appDelegate.username!, password: appDelegate.password!, persistence: .none)
        
        var url = URL(string: webservice)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let urlRequest: Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible = request
        
        AF.request(urlRequest as! URLConvertible, headers: headers).authenticate(with: credential).response { response in
            
        }
```

But I am getting these errors:

Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.URLRequest' to 'Alamofire.URLConvertible' when I do the actual request. How can I convert my Foundation.URLRequest to an Alamofire.URLConvertible?

Thanks,

To do clean on what jsonData is:

```
let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArrayOfDictionaries, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

and jsonArrayOfDictionaries is:

```
var jsonArrayOfDictionaries = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()
```

Its being populated like so:

```
for i in 0..<cellHolder.count {
            
            //Define Dictionary for grading data
            
            var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()
            
            jsonDict["ID"] = cellHolder[i].id
            
            jsonDict["item"] = cellHolder[i].item
            
            jsonDict["Notes"] = cellHolder[i].notes

            jsonArrayOfDictionaries.append(jsonDict)
            
            jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()


}
```

And cellHolder is an Array of a class I created

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    
    var id: Int?
    
    var item: String?
    
    var notes: String?
    
    init(id: Int?, item: String?, notes: Int?) {
       super.init()
        
        self.id = id
        
        self.item = item
        
        self.notes = notes
    }
}
```

Comment: URLConvertible ~ URL. You are using a `URLRequest`, and you are already using some headers in it. How did you create `jsonData`, why not use `AF.request(webservice, method: .post, parameters: yourJSON, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers)`?

Comment: I'll update my question with what jsonData is

Answer (score 0):

Removing the header and just having the Request worked:

```
let credential = URLCredential(user: appDelegate.username!, password: appDelegate.password!, persistence: .none)
        
        var url = URL(string: webservice)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        AF.request(request).authenticate(with: credential).response { response in
            
        }
```